# Remove phone number from text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

How can I remove phone numbers from a string if they are in different formats?

For example I have:

```
text='
(093) 123-34-56 (068) 123 45 67 (095) 123 456 78
    Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)
    Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform
    Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18, TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78'
```

also how can i remove those formats from text

```
 09414241441 095-41-41-441 (096)4141441 091-123-11-22 094 00 111 222
```

How can I remove these phone numbers?

```
(093) 123-34-56 (068) 123 45 67 (095) 123 456 78
```

I have tried `gsub`, but it removes all similar numbers.

Comment: Post what you have tried. Are you using a regex ?

Comment: What phone number formats do you need to remove? [There are a lot of them.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers)

Comment: there are no some specific format it can be different

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking we need to see the evidence of your effort.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation?rq=1 is a very good read when dealing with phone numbers.

Comment: Will the numbers always exist as the first line in the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
text.gsub(/\([0-9]*\)\s[0-9]*(-|\s)[0-9]*(-|\s)[0-9]*/, '')
```

this one will remove the phones in the format you specified in your text:

- (XXX) XXX-XX-XX
- (XXX) XXX XX XX

and always when you are trying to write regex try to use this [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

- `\([0-9]*\)`  need to capture numbers inside an parentheses`(...)`, but as parentheses is special characters in regex so adding `\` before it, `[0-9]` mean need a number and as its not only 1 number inside so adding `*` mean 0 or more number should be inside,
- `\s` need a space after it,
- `(-|\s)` need dash(`-`) (OR `|`) space(`\s`)

for other formats like:

- XXXXXXXXXX
- XXX-XX-XX-XXX
- (XXX)XXXXXXX

beside above one, with the folliwng:

```
text.gsub(/\(*[0-9]+(\)|-)+\s*[0-9]+(-|\s)*[0-9]+(-|\s)*[0-9]+|[0-9]{10}/, '')
```

Comment: regex is very usefull but a bit complicated to understand

Comment: also how can i remove those formats from text
`09414241441 095-41-41-441 (096)4141441`

Comment: writing new notes in post now, just a min

Comment: "how can i remove those formats from text"? You put the necessary requirements into your question, not into comments. The question is ill-defined as is, and adding more conditions/cases in comments only makes the question harder to understand.

Comment: @mohamed-ibrahim, please do _not_ put code, especially additional/changed solution code, in a comment. It's unreadable and makes finding/understanding the solution very difficult. Edit your answer and add the addition. You can use `---` to add a horizontal bar, or incorporate the information as if you'd originally included that information. Don't use "Edit" or "Update" tags in the text though; They're discouraged and will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

As per your format, following regex works

```
/\(\d{3}\)\s+\d{3}[-\s]\d{2,3}[-\s]\d{2}/
```

*Ruby Code*

```
print text.gsub(/\(\d{3}\)\s+\d{3}[-\s]\d{2,3}[-\s]\d{2}/, "")
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/CmvFCz)**

Answer (score 0):

If your text is fixed format, that the numbers will always be the first line in the block, then simply remove the first line:

```
text='
(093) 123-34-56 (068) 123 45 67 (095) 123 456 78
    Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)
    Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform
    Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18, TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78'

text.strip
# => "(093) 123-34-56 (068) 123 45 67 (095) 123 456 78\n    Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)\n    Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform\n    Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18, TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78"
text.strip.lines
# => ["(093) 123-34-56 (068) 123 45 67 (095) 123 456 78\n", "    Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)\n", "    Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform\n", "    Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18, TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78"]
text.strip.lines[1..-1].join
# => "    Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)\n    Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform\n    Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18, TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78"
```

Or:

```
lines = text.strip.lines
# => ["(093) 123-34-56 (068) 123 45 67 (095) 123 456 78\n", "    Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)\n", "    Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform\n", "    Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18, TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78"]
lines.shift
# => "(093) 123-34-56 (068) 123 45 67 (095) 123 456 78\n"
lines.join
# => "    Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)\n    Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform\n    Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18, TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78"
```

Using a regex and `gsub` can work, but it's also more likely to become a maintenance problem.

If the phone numbers will always be on one line, but not necessarily the first, then I'd still use `lines` to break the text into an array, but I'd use `reject` with a regex to match the number pattern to check each line and reject the one with the phone-number-like regex match:

```
lines = text.lines
lines.reject{ |l| l[/\(\d{3}\) \d{3}[ -]\d+{2,3}[ -]\d{2,3}/] }
# => ["\n", "    Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)\n", "    Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform\n", "    Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18, TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78"]

lines.reject{ |l| l[/\(\d{3}\) \d{3}[ -]\d+{2,3}[ -]\d{2,3}/] }.join
# => "\n    Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)\n    Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform\n    Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18, TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78"
```

Note that *not* using `strip` results in the leading "\n" being retained.

Using `lines` to transform the text to an array helps isolate any damage in case something else triggers the pattern match causing inadvertent damage to the text.

Where this approach breaks down is when the phone numbers are scattered throughout the text. I'd still probably use this approach to reduce the text to individual lines though, again to reduce the possible damage if there are false-positives.

Answer (score 0):

```
phone_formats = [/(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{4}/,
                 /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/,
                 /\d{3} \d{3} \d{4}/,
                 /\(\d{3}\) \d{3} \d{3} \d{2}/,
                 /\(\d{3}\) \d{3} \d{2} \d{2}/,
                 /\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}/,
                 /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}/,
                 /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}/]

r = Regexp.union(phone_formats)
  #=> /(?-mix:(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{4})|
  #    (?-mix:\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})|
  #    (?-mix:\d{3} \d{3} \d{4})|
  #    (?-mix:\(\d{3}\) \d{3} \d{3} \d{2})|
  #    (?-mix:\(\d{3}\) \d{3} \d{2} \d{2})|
  #    (?-mix:\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2})|
  #    (?-mix:\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2})|
  #    (?-mix:\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2})/
```

(I have broken the `Regexp.union`'s return value after each `|` for improved readability.)

```
text =<<_
(093) 123-34-56 (068) 123 45 67 (095) 123 456 78
Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)
Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform
Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18,
TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78
_

puts text.gsub(r,'')

Refresh Rate: 60Hz (Native). Backlight: LED (Full Array)
Smart Functionality: Yes - xx TV Streaming Platform
Dimensions (W x H x D): TV without stand (inches) : 28.98x17x3.18,
TV with stand (inches) : 28.98x18.68x7.78
```